# Impedir atualização de plugin no Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugin-wordpress

Olá.

Eu preciso impedir a atualização de um `plugin`. Eu pensei em simplesmente clonar o `plugin` e alterar as informações a seguir:

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: AMP
 * Description: Add AMP support to your WordPress site.
 * Plugin URI: https://github.com/automattic/amp-wp
 * Author: WordPress.com VIP, XWP, Google, and contributors
 * Author URI: https://github.com/Automattic/amp-wp/graphs/contributors
 * Version: 0.7.2
 * Text Domain: amp
 * Domain Path: /languages/
 * License: GPLv2 or later
 *
 * @package AMP
 */
```

Se eu alterar estes dados o `plugin` continua recebendo atualização do fabricante ?

Eu sei que existe `plugins` para resolver este problema. Mas eu não quero ativar um `plugin` só para resolver esse problema específico.

Alguma dica ?

Comment: Já pensou em ir nas configurações ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vou deixar aqui 3 opções de como desabilitar a atualização do plugin.

Baixei aqui a versão 0.7.0 do plugin AMP para testar.

https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/amp.0.7.0.zip

**- Alterando a versão do plugin**

No arquivo principal do plugin (amp.php) altere a versão do plugin (Version) para uma mais alta, neste caso coloquei 100.7.0.

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: AMP
 * Description: Add AMP support to your WordPress site.
 * Plugin URI: https://github.com/automattic/amp-wp
 * Author: WordPress.com VIP, XWP, Google, and contributors
 * Author URI: https://github.com/Automattic/amp-wp/graphs/contributors
 * Version: 100.7.0
 * Text Domain: amp
 * Domain Path: /languages/
 * License: GPLv2 or later
 *
 * @package AMP
 */
```

**- Removendo o plugin da lista de atualização**

Adicione este código no arquivo functions.php do seu tema

```
function remover_update_plugins($value) {
  if (isset($value->response['amp/amp.php'])) {
    unset( $value->response['amp/amp.php'] );
  }
   return $value;
}

add_filter( 'site_transient_update_plugins', 'remover_update_plugins' );
```

**- Desabilitando a atualização de todos os plugins**

Adicione este código ao arquivo wp-config.php

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', true);
```

Comment: Opaa. obrigado irmão. abraço (Y)